# get ajax request url in $.ajaxSetup converters for logging purposes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using $.ajaxSetup with a custom converter for JSON, so we can log errors and do some other stuff, but I would really like to be able to know the request url for the ajax request that the response is for:

example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: { "text json": function(json_string) {
        try {
            var json = $.parseJSON(json_string);
            if (json && json.do_something) {
                // do something if a property is found
            }
            return json;
        } catch (e) {
            // catch any parseJSON errors & send error to our error reporting
            // would like to get the url of the ajax request that this response is for
        }
    }}
});
```

We are having some ajax calls coming back with html for various reasons, and $.parseJSON will fail (as it should), but it would be really helpful to be able to get the url that the ajax request was for, but I don't see an easy way to go about doing that.  Ideas?

Comment: `console.log(this, arguments);` to see what all is available to you within that context.

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried, but it was the window obj and the arguments only had the one argument (the json_string)

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use the ajaxError() global catch all, which gives you access to the xhr obj and the settings (which contains the url)

like so:

```
// let $.parseJSON throw it's error and catch it here, so we can get the url 
// and other useful info that we can include in our custom error
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, err) {
    var message = 'url: ' + settings.url + ' ' + err.message;
    // push message as part of an error to custom error reporting
});

$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: { "text json": function(json_string) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(json_string);
        if (json && json.do_something) {
            // do something if a property is found
        }
        return json;
    }}
});
```